# awk issue, summing lines in various files

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a list of files starting with the word "output", and I want to sum up the total number of rows in all the files.

Here's my strategy:

```
for f in `find outpu*`;do wc -l $f | awk '{x+=$1}END{print $1}' ; done
```

Before piping over, if there were a way I could do something like `>>` to a temporary variable and then run the `awk` command after, I could accomplish this goal.

Any tips?

Comment: Are your "output" files all in the current directory, or do expect to find then in subdirectories?

Comment: You should change the `$1` in your `END`-block to `x`. Still not an effective way to do it. Always worth it to see if you can avoid loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this to see details and sum :

```
wc -l output*
```

and this to see only the sum:

```
wc -l output* | tail -n1 | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Comment: +1, but this is much simpler `cat output* | wc -l` -- a useful use of cat

Answer (score 1):

Here is some stuff for fun, check it out:

```
grep -c . out* | cut -d':' -f2- | paste -sd+ | bc
```

all lines, including empty ones:

```
grep -c '' out* | cut -d':' -f2- | paste -sd+ | bc
```

you can play in `grep` with conditions on lines in files

Answer (score 0):

Watch out, this find command will only find stuff in your current directory if there is one file matching `outpu*`.

One way of doing it:

```
awk 'END{print NR}' $(find 'outpu*')
```

Provided that there is not an insane amount of matching filenames that overflows the maximum command length limit of your shell.

Comment: `find 'outpu*'` does not do what you want.  Further, If you are looking for `outpu*` in the current directory, there is no need for `find`.  If you want to search subdirs also, then use `find . -name 'outpu*'`.  Also, `awk 'END{print NR}' $(find -name 'outpu*')` would fail if there are any whitespace characters in any file name.  You can avoid that while still keeping your `awk` approach by using: `find . -name 'outpu*' -exec cat {} ';' | awk 'END{print NR}'`.